# How can I run getServerSideProps con funcitonal component with Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is possible to run the server side props within a component in NextJS?
As I understand, getServerSideProps fetches the data when entering into my page, but, is possible for it to run when rendering a component?

This is because I have the following:

```
export default function FichaTecnica(props) {
  const indicador = props.data;

  const crumbs = [{
    text: 'Chihuahua en Datos',
    href: '/chihuahua-en-datos'
  }, {
    text: indicador.modulo.temaIndicador,
    href: `/chihuahua-en-datos/temas/${indicador.modulo.id}/indicadores`
  }, {
    text: indicador.nombre
  }];

  return (
    <>
      <Container sx={{ mb: 3, mt: 3 }}>
        <PageBreadcrumb crumbs={[...crumbs]} />
        <TopData info={indicador} />
        <DataSheet datasheet={indicador} />
        <GraphBox history={indicador} />
        <MapButton mapa={indicador.mapa} />
        <IndicadorOwner authorID={indicador.createdBy} indicadorDate={indicador.updatedAt} />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const idIndicador = context.params.idIndicador;
  const res = await fetch(
    `${process.env.INDICADORES_BASE_URL}/indicadores/${idIndicador}`
  );

  const data = await res.json();

  if (res.status === 200) {
    return {
      props: { ...data },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      props: {
        data: [],
      },
    };
  }
}
```

I want to fetch data on the IndicadorOwner component, and inside of it I have:

```
const IndicadorOwner = ({ ownerID, indicadorDate }, props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Title variant='h4' component='h2'>Responsable</Title>
            <Grid container className={`${style.indicadorOwner}`}>

                <Grid item sm={12} md={8} lg={6} xl={6} className={`${style.cardBody}`}>
                    <Box className={`${style.cardContainer}`}>
                        <Box className={`${style.imageContainer}`}>
                            <Avatar alt='Bobby P.' src='https://media.gq.com.mx/photos/61f8318a45749103d307bf61/2:3/w_1124,h_1686,c_limit/robert%20pattinson.jpg' sx={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}>
                            </Avatar>
                        </Box>
                        <Box className={`${style.userInformation}`} >
                            <Typography variant='caption' component='h4' className={`${style.cardData}`}>
                                24 de Julio 2022
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant='subtitle' component='h3' className={`${style.cardData}`}>
                                Robert Pattinson
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant='subtitle' component='h5' className={`${style.cardData}`}>
                                Robert Douglas Thomas Pattinson (born 13 May 1986) is an English actor. Known for starring in both big-budget and independent films.
                            </Typography>
                            <br />
                        </Box>
                        <Box className={`${style.contact}`}>
                            <Link href='mailto:Bobby.P@gmail.com' className={`${style.link}`}>
                                <Avatar sx={{ width: 30, height: 30 }} className={`${style.emailIcon}`}>
                                    <MailIcon />
                                </Avatar>
                            </Link>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const idUsuario = context.params.idUsuario;

    const res = await fetch(
        `${process.env.INDICADORES_BASE_URL}/usuarios/${idUsuario}/profile`
    );

    const data = await res.json();
    if (res.status === 200) {
        return {
            props: { ...data },
        };
    } else {
        return {
            props: {
                data: [],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to use the "ownerID" into the fetching in order to retrieve my user, but, is this possible or is this the correct approach?

Comment: First of all, getServerSideProps only can be executed on the page not in the components, as it executes on the server-side, but why do you want to execute it in the component, not in the page which wraps that component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things

1. Fetch all the data you need in `getServerSideProps`, potentially multiple queries and pass all the data you need into `FichaTecnica` to populate all components

or

2. Fetch some "key ID's" and pass those into FichaTecnica. Then fetch additional missing data from within the component (from the frontend), e.g. using useEffect

`getServerSideProps` only fetches data, not return components. Use the data to hydrate components.